# An expression for venturing into an experiment with unknown consequences without much knowledge

Tags: phrase-request

I'm looking for an expression for venturing into an experiment with unknown consequences without much knowledge. I vaguely remember there was something from ancient Greece or in Latin that was signifying that.

Comment: Are you looking for an actual Latin expression (like et cetera for "and so on") or an English word with Latin roots (like experiment from Latin experimentum)?

Comment: @JamesK yes, that would be a plus

Comment: Keep in mind that [Titles are for titles, and questions belong in your question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4797/9161). That portion of the [Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4783/9161) explains why in a bit more detail.

Comment: (Actually [this answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4773/9161) that is linked to indirectly in the posts I mentioned above is the most relevant guidance)

Comment: *"fools rush in (...where angels fear to tread)"?* That's the usual device for expressing someone engaging in an experiment where they know little, not even the possible consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would fit:
[American Heritage Dictionary "heuristic" (2)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=heuristic)

2. Of or constituting an educational method in which learning takes place through discoveries that result from investigations made by the student.